# How to use Importrange and filter function with a cell reference

Tags: google-sheets

I want to use filter function with a database from another google sheet website, whenever they have the same "asset number"

I used the formula
=Filter({IMPORTRANGE(database WEBSITE, "R9:U")}, index({IMPORTRANGE(database WEBSITE, "Asset report!A9:A")},,1)="1631870")

it works, but I want to change the "=" to A2 of the master sheet then it just doesnt work, having #N/A, with no result found message

=Filter({IMPORTRANGE(WEBSITE, "R9:U")}, index({IMPORTRANGE(WEBSITE, "Asset report!A9:A")},,1)=A2)

How can I modify the "A2" to make it works? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Exact copy of [How to use Importrange and filter function with a cell reference](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/179818355) that has an answer.